# Way to execute files from browser extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, safari-extension

Can main browsers(Firefox/Chrome/Safari) open and execute(open with params) files from local directories? The idea is to execute files(bat/exe) and have messaging from browser extension to local files.

Comment: Yes, Yes / Yes, No / No, No.

Comment: I've answered whether it's possible to open, or to "execute" files from local directories in the given browsers (Firefox / Chrome / Safari). If you want a detailed answer, then you have to provide context to the question, because as it stands right now, it's way too broad. At the very least, describe what you're want to achieve and what you've tried to reach this goal.